# Get all file all subfolders and all hidden file with glob

Tags: php, glob

In my recurive function to zip a whole folders i have this piece of code
glob($path. '/*')
that give me all files and subfolders matching my $path.

[Here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#68869) I read that with glob I can get even hidden files ".filename" with
glob('{,.}*', GLOB_BRACE)
How to merge in one expression my needs?
I tried
glob('{/,.}*', GLOB_BRACE)
but only give me the files
I tried
glob('{/,.,}*', GLOB_BRACE)
but I get crazy results

I already filteres . and ..

How to merge

```
glob($dir . '/*')
```

and

```
    glob('{,.}*', GLOB_BRACE)
```

Answer (score 13):

To get all folders/files (even the hidden ones):

```
$result = glob($path . '{,.}[!.,!..]*',GLOB_MARK|GLOB_BRACE);
```

This will prevent listing "." or ".." in the result.

Comment: This does not find the legal filename `...filename.ext`

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried this?

```
glob($path. '/{,.}*', GLOB_BRACE);
```

Answer (score 7):

I am answering here in case anyone else is looking as this appears high on Google.

**Solution 1 - glob only**

This uses a glob that is tailored to skip '.' and '..' special directories. It matches anything that:

- isn't hidden with a '.'
- is hidden with a '.' but is followed a non '.' character
- starts with '..' but has at least one character after it

```
$globbed = glob("{*,.[!.]*,..?*}", GLOB_BRACE);
var_dump($globbed);
```

**Solution 2 - globignore**

This is a function to mimic the behaviour of [globignore in bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Filename-Expansion.html).

```
function globignore(array $ignore, $glob, $glob_flags = 0)
{
    $globbed = glob($glob, $glob_flags);
    return array_filter($globbed, function ($f) use ($ignore)
    {
        $base = basename($f);
        foreach($ignore as $i)
        {
            if ($i == $base) return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
}
$globbed = globignore(['.','..'], "{*,.*}", GLOB_BRACE);
var_dump($globbed);
```

They appear to execute in almost exactly the same time on my system. **Solution 1** requires less code but **solution 2** is easier to include more terms to ignore.

Comment: Two years after - I used this `glob`-only solution, and it is the only correct one here.

Answer (score 7):

This returns hidden files and folders, but not `.` or `..`:

```
glob('{,.}*[!.]*', GLOB_MARK | GLOB_BRACE);
```

Example result:

```
file
file.
file.ext
folder/
...hiddenfile
...hiddenfile.ext
..hiddenfolder/
.h
.hiddenfile
.hiddenfolder/
```

**Additional information**
Houman tried to target `.` or `..`  with `[!.,!..]`, but as this is a character class it is not possible to target strings with a defined length. This means `[!.]` and `[!..]` are identical and target both strings not containing an unlimited amount of dots (., .., ..., ...., etc.). Because of that I used `[!.]` only. Targeting strings is only possible with curly braces like `{jpg,png}`. You find a [good explanation in the php.net comments](https://www.php.net/manual/function.glob.php#88250).

Although I used the flag [`GLOB_MARK`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php#:%7E:text=GLOB_MARK) to add an ending slash to folders.

Comment: This does not find a file named `filename.` - ending in a dot.

Comment: @rexkogitans, `/{,.}*[!.]*`

Answer (score 1):

The `glob()` method returns an array. So if you want to merge two different `glob` results...

```
$merged = array_merge(glob($dir . '/*'), glob('{,.}*', GLOB_BRACE));
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you've found already the solution, but in case you were looking for a way that gives you the files and directories, recursively and taking care of hidden files, this was what I got:

```
function rglob($pattern, $flags = 0) {
    $files = glob($pattern, $flags);

    foreach (glob(dirname($pattern).'/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT) as $dir) {
        $files = array_merge($files, $this->rglob($dir.'/'.basename($pattern), $flags));
    }

    return $files;
}
```