# Unlink/Delete files which starts with a dot

Tags: php

I'm trying to delete (unlink) files which starts with a dot.

This is my approach:

```
$dirList = glob('*');
foreach ($dirList as $file) {
  if(time() - filectime($file) > 7200) {
     unlink($file);
  }
}
```

Its deleting every file which is older than 2 hours, but only those which dont start with a dot. Files which starts with a dot are not deleting. How can I solve this? I was thinking about using exec, but I want to use the php way if there are any possibilities to solve this using php.

Comment: remember that  . and ..  are system files  .. (this directroy and parent directory  )  .. sio be careful before delete each  files that start with .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33059445/1207346

Comment: My first question would be does `glob` show hidden (files starting with a dot) by default or do you have to tell it to, and of course the answer is no

Comment: What you are doing seems to be inherently dangerous.

Comment: @Jamie_D why so? there are NO system files in that folder.

Comment: Because anytime you start messing with hidden files you should be ready for danger, inb4 how do i restore my deleted hidden files

Comment: If you **must** do this, than I would add an ignore array `$ignore = array('.','..')` then  `if(!in_array($file, $ignore)) { ... }`

Comment: @Dale but if there are no hidden files at all, only txt files which have to be deleted sometimes, how would that be dangerous?

Comment: You may accidentally traverse a folder, who knows what could go wrong... all we're saying is be careful

Comment: sure I am. thanks for the warning! also, your answer seems to work. thank you very much.

Comment: From the documentation **Please note that glob('*') ignores all 'hidden' files by default.**

Comment: also, is there a safer way for deleting files which starts with a dot?

Comment: `$files = glob('{,.}*', GLOB_BRACE); `