# Getting all folders and images and return it as an array

Tags: php

I have different subfolders in my folder 'images' on my server. Now I want to return a array with the image name and also the subfolder in which the image is.

Actually I only get the images if I specify the subfolder:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=UTF-8');

echo "var images = [];\n";
$folder = 'images/';
$all_images = glob($folder."{*.jpg, *.JPG, *.JPEG, *.png, *.PNG}", GLOB_BRACE);
$count = count($all_images);
for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

    echo "images[".$i."] = {};\n";
    echo "images[".$i."].src = '".$all_images[$i]."';\n";
    echo "images[".$i."].name = '".substr($all_images[$i],strlen($folder),strpos($all_images[$i], '.')-strlen($folder))."';\n";
    echo "images[".$i."].modified = '".date('YmdHis', filemtime($all_images[$i])).$i."';\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: here is your answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906185/get-all-file-all-subfolders-and-all-hidden-file-with-glob

Comment: this answer could be of some use also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25257717/php-recursive-directory-search-using-glob-for-multiple-file-types